Activate graph after long press react native gesture handler
I am using React Native Echarts, which allows me to use interactive graphs so that the user can press on different data points and tooltips will display the data. The Issue is that I want to activate the interactive portion of the graph after the user does a long press on the graph (let's say 500 ms). Then, once the user releases the press, the tooltip should disappear and the graph should not be interactive unless there is another long press. Any idea on how to do this?
I'm aware that Echarts also support React-Native-Gesture-Handler so I tried adding the LongPress gesture but it made the graph become completely uninteractive, even after holding a long press.
Here's my code:
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import { black, green, red, white } from '@/constants/Colors';
import IntradayInterface from '@/src/components/alphaVantage/interfaces/IntradayInterface';
import DailyAdjustedInterface from '@/src/components/alphaVantage/interfaces/DailyAdjustedInterface';
import WeeklyAdjustedInterface from '@/src/components/alphaVantage/interfaces/WeeklyAdjustedInterface';
import MonthlyAdjustedInterface from '@/src/components/alphaVantage/interfaces/MonthlyAdjustedInterface';
import * as echarts from 'echarts/core';
import { CandlestickChart, BarChart } from 'echarts/charts';
import { GridComponent, VisualMapComponent, BrushComponent, TooltipComponent, DataZoomComponent, LegendComponent } from 'echarts/components';
import { SVGRenderer, SvgChart } from '@wuba/react-native-echarts';
import { StockTimePeriod } from './DatasetEnums';
import { Gesture } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

echarts.use([SVGRenderer, CandlestickChart, BarChart, GridComponent, VisualMapComponent, BrushComponent, TooltipComponent, DataZoomComponent, LegendComponent]);

interface GraphProps {
    symbol: string,
    timePeriod: StockTimePeriod,
    oneMin: IntradayInterface,
    hourly: IntradayInterface,
    daily: DailyAdjustedInterface,
    weekly: WeeklyAdjustedInterface,
    monthly: MonthlyAdjustedInterface
};

function extractStockData(data: IntradayInterface | DailyAdjustedInterface | WeeklyAdjustedInterface | MonthlyAdjustedInterface){
    let priceData = [];
    let dates = [];
    let volumeData = [];
    for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(data.interval)) {
        dates.push(k);
        const open = Number(v.open);
        const close = Number(v.close);
        const high = Number(v.high);
        const low = Number(v.low);
        const volume = Number(v.volume);
        priceData.push([open, close, low, high]);
        volumeData.push(volume);
    };
    priceData = priceData.reverse();
    dates = dates.reverse();
    volumeData = volumeData.reverse();
    return { priceData, dates, volumeData };
}

const Graph = (props: GraphProps) => {

  const longPressGraph = Gesture.LongPress();

  // 1min, hourly, daily, weekly, monthly data arrays
  let oneMin = extractStockData(props.oneMin);
  let oneMinData = oneMin.priceData;
  let oneMinDates = oneMin.dates;
  let oneMinVolume = oneMin.volumeData;
  
  let hourly = extractStockData(props.hourly);
  let hourlyData = hourly.priceData;
  let hourlyDates = hourly.dates;
  let hourlyVolume = hourly.volumeData;

  let daily = extractStockData(props.daily);
  let dailyData = daily.priceData;
  let dailyDates = daily.dates;
  let dailyVolume = daily.volumeData;

  let weekly = extractStockData(props.weekly);
  let weeklyData = weekly.priceData;
  let weeklyDates = weekly.dates;
  let weeklyVolume = weekly.volumeData;

  let monthly = extractStockData(props.monthly);
  let monthlyData = monthly.priceData;
  let monthlyDates = monthly.dates;
  let monthlyVolume = monthly.volumeData;

  if(props.symbol != null){
    if(props.oneMin === undefined) {
      Alert.alert("Unable to get Stock details, try again later, oneMin");
      return;
    }
    if(props.hourly === undefined) {
        Alert.alert("Unable to get Stock details, try again later, sixtyMin");
        return;
    }
    if(props.daily === undefined){
        Alert.alert("Unable to get Stock details, try again later, daily");
        return;
    }
    if(props.weekly === undefined){
        Alert.alert("Unable to get Stock details, try again later, weekly");
        return;
    }
    if(props.monthly === undefined){
        Alert.alert("Unable to get Stock details, try again later, monthly");
        return;
    } 
  };

  let stockData = [oneMinData, hourlyData, dailyData, weeklyData, monthlyData];
  let stockDates = [oneMinDates, hourlyDates, dailyDates, weeklyDates, monthlyDates];
  let stockVolumes = [oneMinVolume, hourlyVolume, dailyVolume, weeklyVolume, monthlyVolume];

  const svgRef = useRef<any>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const option = {
      animation: true,
      darkMode: true,
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
          type: 'cross'
        },
        backgroundColor: '#222',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#777',
        padding: 10,
        textStyle: {
          color: white
        },
        position: function (pos: number[], params: any, el: any, elRect: any, size: { viewSize: number[]; }) {
          const obj: Record<string, number> = {
            top: 10
          };
          obj[['left', 'right'][+(pos[0] < size.viewSize[0] / 2)]] = 30;
          return obj;
        }
      },
      axisPointer: {
        link: [
          {
              xAxisIndex: 'all'
          }
        ],
        label: {
          backgroundColor: green
        }
      },
      grid: [
        {
          left: '10%',
          right: '8%',
          height: '65%'
        },
        {
          left: '10%',
          right: '8%',
          top: '81%',
          height: '15%'
        }
      ],
      xAxis: [
        {
          type: 'category',
          data: stockDates[props.timePeriod],
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisLine: { onZero: false },
          splitLine: { show: false },
          min: 'dataMin',
          max: 'dataMax',
        },
        {
          type: 'category',
          gridIndex: 1,
          data: stockDates[props.timePeriod],
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisLine: { onZero: false },
          axisTick: { show: false },
          splitLine: { show: false },
          axisLabel: { show: false },
          min: 'dataMin',
          max: 'dataMax'
        }
      ],
      yAxis: [
        {
          scale: true,
          splitArea: {
            show: true
          }
        },
        {
          scale: true,
          gridIndex: 1,
          splitNumber: 2,
          axisLabel: { show: false },
          axisLine: { show: false },
          axisTick: { show: false },
          splitLine: { show: false }
        }
      ],
      dataZoom: [
        {
          type: 'inside',
          xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
          start: 0,
          end: 100
        },
        {
          show: false,
          xAxisIndex: [0, 1],
          type: 'slider',
          top: '85%',
          start: 0,
          end: 100
        }
      ],
      series: [
        {
          name: props.symbol,
          type: 'candlestick',
          data: stockData[props.timePeriod],
          itemStyle: {
            color: green,
            color0: red,
            borderColor: undefined,
            borderColor0: undefined
          }
        },
        {
          name: 'Volume',
          type: 'bar',
          xAxisIndex: 1,
          yAxisIndex: 1,
          data: stockVolumes[props.timePeriod]
        }
      ]
    };
    let chart: any;
    if (svgRef.current) {
      chart = echarts.init(svgRef.current, 'light', {
        renderer: 'svg',
        width: 400,
        height: 500,
      });
      chart.setOption(option);
    }
    return () => chart?.dispose();
  }, [props.timePeriod]);

  return <SvgChart ref={svgRef} useRNGH gesture={longPressGraph}/>;
}

export default Graph;

This is what the graph looks like without any interaction:

And this is what it looks like with interaction:

